# How to get Device Unique Id in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, deviceid

Is there any way to find out unique device id in react js? As I want to do that no user can request for otp from same device more than three times in a day.

Comment: You can generate an id and save it in localStorage. That could be your device id. Identifying a device, if it is even possible, surely would be some kind of privacy breach and can be easily abused by nefarious actors.

Comment: OK .  Thank you. I will try this.